# Underlying value of an NSDate (DateValue)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

To debug a DB app I need to verify the datevalue against the value that arrives in my SQLiteDB.
Is there a way to show the double(?)-value of an NSDate (in code covert it to a double?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently solution depends on what value is stored in your database.

Have a look at `-timeIntervalSince1970` method - it may do for you as timeintervals are often used for storing date values in db.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I am looking for the reverse direction. I need to debug the NSDate value as double before it is inserted into the DB ?

Comment: So use timeIntervalSince1970 method - it will return the number of seconds passed since 01.01.1970. What other double value you expect to get from NSDate?